# Can a force manipulator fix bugs?

Tags: star-wars

If I am a Jedi/Sith, and to make some extra money I work daytime as a developer.

Can I fix bugs by manipulating the Force? If I can which I guess that's the case, is this permanent fix or it works for just as long as I am channeling it?

Comment: Not sure this is answerable in canon but its a good question.

Comment: Only if you use the Light side ... else "Fear is the path to the dark side…fear leads to anger…anger leads to hate…hate leads to suffering."

Comment: If you did, you should be able to do the entire programming work with the Force as well, right? On the other hand, then you should not need to fix any bugs (assuming the Force makes stuff bug-free). As for the result, I would say it's permanent.

Comment: Isn't this primarily opinion based?

Comment: I suppose the force guides you when you start troubleshooting towards the direction of fixing the bugs

Comment: or if you lose your temper and start banging the keyboard may be you become a sith?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably possible, the now Legends game and novelization of the game, The Force Unleashed, had Starkiller storm the junkyard planet, Raxus Prime, where former Jedi, Kazdan Paratus, made a replica of the Jedi Temple, with working Scrap Droids fully powered by the Force and some form of remnant Guard and Probe droid programming still on them, the Force allowed them to function without any other power source and the programming allowed them to function independently to Kazdan, it's also worth noting that his specialty was the combined use of the Force and Tech, ultimately resulting in him using those Hybrid Tech-Force droids.

EDIT: Kazdan wasn't much for fighting, he was basically part of the Jedi R&D and IIRC, he also made a good amount of credits selling his hybrid droids, and to address your questions, you'd probably need to passively send Force energy to the machine and it'd need some form of programming to follow so you'd not need to stay rooted to it.

When Kazdan died, all the Force Constructs fell apart, so he did mantain a passive effort to keep them all up, it was probably minuscule once the Force was encapsulated in the Droids, but necessary nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a good idea. Bugs are usually fixed by rewriting, removing or otherwise editing code. It would be very complex to achieve the feat of writing code by manipulating matter, for example, and if the code was somehow automagically written, rather than with your own conscious effort and understanding, it could end up being [unmaintainable](https://github.com/Droogans/unmaintainable-code).

You could, I think, "fix" bugs [Ff]orcefully using The Dark Side, with a crude [Electronic Manipulation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Electronic_Manipulation) technique, but since the code itself would still be broken, your solution would not be portable, though it may be permanent on the hardware in question.

Perhaps you should try meditating...